# Get old symfony installer

Tags: php, docker, symfony

Does anyone know how, can I get an old version of symfony installer ?

Let me explain.
I need to launch local environment with an old symfony version (3.4) and In my Dockerfile, I have this command line
`RUN wget https://get.symfony.com/cli/installer -O - | bash && mv /root/.symfony/bin/symfony /usr/local/bin/symfony`

But here, it's the latest stable symfony version which is get, and in my case, I want to get symfony 3.4 cli version.

Thank for yours answers.

I try to get 3.4 version with this url :
`RUN wget https://get.symfony.com/cli/installer/3.4 -O - | bash && mv /root/.symfony/bin/symfony /usr/local/bin/symfony`

But it doesn't work.

Comment: Try this: https://symfony.com/doc/current/setup.html#creating-symfony-applications

Comment: maybe you need to specify the version directly in the url :
RUN wget https://get.symfony.com/cli/installer -O - | bash -s -- --version 3.4 && mv /root/.symfony/bin/symfony /usr/local/bin/symfony